# Cannot call setNoRender() on viewRenderer in postDispatch() in a Zend Framework Controller Plugin

Tags: php, zend-framework

Calling setNoRender() or indeed any methods on the viewRenderer helper seem to have no effect in a controller plugin.

```
class TestPlugin extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{
    public function postDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
    {
        $viewRenderer = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('viewRenderer');
        $viewRenderer->setNoRender();
    }
}
```

The view script still renders. And the plugin is definitely running as I can put echoes in here and they will output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll have to put this in your `postDispatch` of your Controller Plugin.

```
$viewRenderer = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getExistingHelper('viewRenderer');
$viewRenderer->setNeverRender(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this work in any other hooks, for example preDispatch()?

Comment: None of them. preDispatch, postDispatch, dispatchLoopStartup, dispatchLoopShutdown, routeStartup, routeShutdown - none of them seem to work with the viewRenderer.

Comment: try getting the frontcontroller instance then call $front->setParam('noViewRenderer', TRUE); Although this will only work in preDispatch()

Comment: Setting 'noViewRenderer' as param, will actually disable the complete view, instead of not rendering it.

Comment: $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender();

Answer (score 1):

in case if someone wants to disable both layout and view using controller plugin, here is the preDispatch hook that i got working with the help of different articles and answers, including this one.
Hope it helps someone, and saves some time.

```
// in Controller Plugin
public function preDispatch(){
        //if  its an AJAX request then disable layout and view.
        if ($this->_request->isXmlHttpRequest() || isset($_GET['ajax'])){
            // disable layout
            $layout = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getExistingHelper('Layout');
            $layout->disableLayout();
            // disable view
            $viewRenderer = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getExistingHelper('viewRenderer');
            $viewRenderer->setNeverRender(true);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are welcome. I used it in Zend Framework 1.11. Not sure if still valid for Zend Framework 2

Answer (score 0):

I also could not figure out how to do this from the controller plugin initialization script.   However, there is a simple workaround.  You can do this in the preDispatch of your base controller with the following, standard code:

```
$this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);
```

All your controllers should be inheriting from this base controller, which itself extends Zend_Controller_Action.